# php exec function is not working on cpanel

Tags: php, web

I am using exec php built in function in my project. It is working perfectly on my local but on my cpanel it is not working perfectly.
The code on local and cpanel is same so I don't know why it is not working.

I know `exec` function is disabled by default in live server but I have asked support and they are saying that they have enabled `exec` function but it is not working in my project.

exec code on local:

```
exec("swetest -edir$sweph -b$utdatenow -ut$utnow -p0123456789DAttt -eswe -house$my_longitude,$my_latitude,$h_sys -flsj -g, -head", $out);
```

response on local:

```
194.2488544
```

also give data in `$out`  in array

exec code on cpanel:

```
exec("swetest -edir$sweph -b$utdatenow -ut$utnow -p0123456789DAttt -eswe -house$my_longitude,$my_latitude,$h_sys -flsj -g, -head", $out);
```

response on cpanel:

```
return empty value.
```

`$out` is also empty ...

I don't know where the issue coming?
Can someone help me to fix this?

Comment: Are you sure the `swetest` program is installed on your server? Add `2>&1` to the end of the command to see error messages.

Comment: No idea about this..
is it necessary to install this before to use this..??
if yes then how can i install swetest?

Comment: Download the Swiss Ephemeris software from https://www.astro.com/ftp/swisseph/ or https://github.com/aloistr/swisseph

Answer (score 1):

On cPanel, go to MultiPHP Manager. Then Open the User Domain Settings tab, find the domain in the list and click the PHP-FPM Settings.
In the "Disable Functions" paste these and then click "Update":
passthru
system
shell_exec

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Try check your php.ini configurations for cPanel probably the exec function was disabled or display_errors is set to false, in case you not sure try copy your local php.ini content to your server php.ini and try again.